# Pass string from PHP to onclick handler of anchor tag

Tags: php, javascript, alert

I am trying to pass a value on the server side to the `onclick` handler of `a` tag, but it is giving different result on the client side when I click on the link.

My PHP code:

```
$any="link1";
echo(" <a id='link1' href='#' onclick='VisibleFalse($any)'>[+]</a><span><b>$candidatename</b></span>");
```

I want to pass the string `"link1"` to the function `VisibleFalse`, which is showing the string as an alert:

```
function VisibleFalse(ID)
{
    alert(ID);
}
```

But it is printing `"http://localhost/..."` in the alert.

I would appreciate any of your suggestions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is, you're passing a string and you forgot to add quotes to it so that the **end result** would be a string inside that JavaScript function. Here's a better way to look at this:

```
$any="link1";
// First, echo isn't a function. It can be faked to be used as one, but that's not recommended
// Second, sort out your quoting like this:
echo '<a id="link1" href="#" onclick="VisibleFalse(\''.$any.'\')">[+]</a><span><b>'.$candidatename.'</b></span>';

// OR
echo "<a id='link1' href='#' onclick='VisibleFalse(\"$any\")'>[+]</a><span><b>$candidatename</b></span>";
```

Answer (score 0):

String literals in JavaScript must be quoted.

```
onclick='VisibleFalse(&quot;$any&quot;)'>
```

(But intrinsic event attributes considered to be more pain then they are worth, as is Javascript embedded in HTML embedded in PHP. Use [unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) instead.)

You also need to make sure that `$any` does not include any quote characters that would terminate the string literal (and you should probably be making it HTML safe with `htmlspecialchars` so it doesn't terminate the attribute value)

Answer (score 0):

Use the HTML Unicode (other characters can be found [here](http://www.ascii.cl/htmlcodes.htm)) equivalent to quotations `&#39;`.

```
echo(" <a id='link1' href='#' onclick='javascript:VisibleFalse(&#39;$any&#39;)'>[+]</a><span><b>$candidatename</b></span>");
```

Comment: Why have you added a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) to that piece of JavaScript? There is no loop.

Comment: Just a habit (lol), but the above alerts out the value from the variable `$any`. Regards

Comment: Character references in HTML are Unicode not ASCII (39 happens to be `'` in both character sets, but it is only ASCII because of the overlap).